# MongoDB sharded cluster and replica sets sharing servers

Tags: mongodb, database-performance

I'm trying to define the architecture for a production sharded mongoDB server, I see in the documentation that each shard has to contain 3 replica-sets. I would like to have the sharding advantages(being able to compute distributed queries in the nodes depending on the shard key) and the replication failover functionality, but reducing the budget (and the number of servers).

The idea is to use small machines of 7GB RAM and 2 core 2GHz:

I have been searching and I found some people was installing the different replicas of the shards sharing nodes in the following schema:

```
Server 1: shard1, rep-shard2, arbitrer3
Server 2: shard2, rep-shard3, arbitrer1
Server 3: shard3, rep-shard1, arbitrer2
```

I tried this using docker and it works, however I don't know if I can have any performance issues by sharing the same node as the replica-set and the shard.

Another option is to use 4 cluster and 2 shards with the following schema which I don't like that much (1 more node, 1 less shard) but maybe would be could be better in terms of performance.

```
Server1: shard1,
Server2: rep-shard1 arbitrer2
Server3: shard2,
Server4: rep-shard2 arbitrer1
```

Comment: As this question asks about machine specifics it might be worth checking out https://serverfault.com/ to see if it would be a better match over there.

Comment: thank you @JasonAller, I did not know about the serverfault.com web.

Answer (score 1):

Replication is used for fault tolerance; sharding is used for performance (to scale out).

If you have a total of 3 servers, you should simply set up a 3-node replica set.

Your post misuses some of the terminology which makes it difficult to figure out what it is you are saying. "3 replica-sets" for example means 9 or more servers are involved.

Comment: Yes, I want both, falut tolerance and the possibility to scale out and improving the performance. If I can't shard using the same machines, I will probably choose to simply use a 3 replica set mongo.

Comment: The point of sharding is to use additional hardware (2 servers instead of 1). If you put all shards on the same server you don't get that benefit so sharding is pointless.

Comment: I don't think you are using "scale out" properly either.

Comment: Sorry, I migth not have explained correctly. The idea is to have the 3 shards in different server, and use the same servers to keep the replica-sets of this shards. I would use a distribution so each shard and its replica-sets are always in different server too. (see example 1 on the question)

Comment: If you want to run 3 shards, you need a minimum of 9 servers. I suggest you read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/ if you have not already and use the proper terminology and grammar. I do not understand what "3 shards in different server" or "replica set in shard" mean.

Comment: That's not actually true, you can run 3 shards with 1 member replica set, using only 3 servers. Or use arbitrers instead of 1 replica set.

Comment: For testing purposes, sure. You can run everything on the same machine. How is this relevant?